# Materialize button not working in Laravel

Tags: laravel, radio-button, materialize, laravel-blade

I am using materialize css for design and I've been wondering why my radio button is not working - by not working I mean it's not clickable.

But that is if the radio is within the `foreach($segments as $segment)` but if it's placed outside it, the radio button is working just fine.

I couldn't get hold of where I went wrong. I've been stuck here ever since. If you could help, it will be such a great pleasure! Advance thanks!

```
@foreach($segments as $segment)
      @foreach($collars as $collar)
      @if($collar->boolIsActive == 1)
      <div class="col s12" style="margin-top:20px;">
        <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion" style="border:none;" @if($segment->strSegmentID != $collar->strSegmentFK) hidden @endif>
          <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header" style="background-color:#00838f; color:white; height:30px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:50px; font-size:18px">{{ $collar->strSegStyleName }}</div>
            <div class="collapsible-body row overflow-x" style="padding:20px;">  
              <div class="col s12">
                @foreach($patterns as $pattern)
                <div class="col s2" @if($pattern->strSegPStyleCategoryFK != $collar->strSegStyleCatID) hidden @endif>
                  <img class="materialboxed responsive-img" src="{{URL::asset($pattern->strSegPImage)}}">
                  <p>
                    <input name="rdb_pattern" type="radio" class="filled-in" id="{{$pattern->strSegPatternID}}" />
                    <label for="{{$pattern->strSegPatternID}}">{{$pattern->strSegPName}}</label>
                  </p>
                </div>
                @endforeach
              </div>                 
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      @endif
      @endforeach
      @endforeach
```

Comment: Have you checked if the radio buttons you generate in the loop have different ids?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out!! Here's what I did.

```
@foreach($segments as $i => $segment)
      @foreach($collars as $j => $collar)
      @if($collar->boolIsActive == 1)
      <div class="col s12" style="margin-top:20px;">
        <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion" style="border:none;" @if($segment->strSegmentID != $collar->strSegmentFK) hidden @endif>
          <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header" style="background-color:#00838f; color:white; height:30px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:50px; font-size:18px">{{ $collar->strSegStyleName }}</div>
            <div class="collapsible-body row overflow-x" style="padding:20px;">  
              <div class="col s12">
                @foreach($patterns as $k => $pattern)
                <div class="col s2" @if($pattern->strSegPStyleCategoryFK != $collar->strSegStyleCatID) hidden @endif>
                  <img class="materialboxed responsive-img" src="{{URL::asset($pattern->strSegPImage)}}">
                  <p>
                    <input name="rdb_pattern{{ $collar->strSegStyleCatID }} {{ $i+1 }}" type="radio" class="filled-in" id="{{$pattern->strSegPatternID}}{{ $i+1 }}{{ $j+1 }}{{ $k+1 }}" />
                    <label for="{{$pattern->strSegPatternID}}{{ $i+1 }}{{ $j+1 }}{{ $k+1 }}">{{$pattern->strSegPName}}</label>
                  </p>
                </div>
                @endforeach
              </div>                 
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      @endif
      @endforeach
      @endforeach
```